# Android - Cancel the sleeping timer task

Tags: multithreading, timer, timertask

I am using timer and timer task in my app. I want to cancel the timer task by using .cancel() -> This works fine but few times I want to cancel the running timer task which is in sleep. When I use .cancel(), it doesn't work. Cancelling timer also doesn't wake up current sleeping task. Can someone guide me?

Answer (score 0):

Because the device is in sleep mode. You've to set this to wake up the device if needed:

```
    final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE); 
    mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
    mWakeLock.acquire();

    new AsyncParsingTask().execute();
```

Comment: How can the device be in sleep mode? only the thread is in sleep mode in my case, I need to wake that thread up as another thread is ready to run its execution.

Comment: And also I am using timer and timertask